Real time SMS from Sales Cloud to Customers via Marketing Cloud
We currently use a third party system built in our sales cloud to send transactional SMS alerts to our customers.
We use Marketing Cloud to send monthly emails primarily.
As they are monthly activities, they are not real time (i.e once in a month we prepare csv data from Sales Cloud -> import into Data Extension -> one time Email Send).
We want to know whether it is possible in real time to send SMS though.
All these SMSs will be transactional and not promotional.
Is it possible to send SMS from Sales Cloud to Customers via Marketing Cloud ?.

First, "Transactional SMS sending" doesn't exist, particularly because Marketing Cloud solely forwards SMS to a carrier.
There are some ways to send SMS to Sales Cloud contacts by Marketing Cloud:

Using Journey Builder in Marketing Cloud: you can build a journey builder in Marketing Cloud where it will trigger by some specific criteria to inject contacts into the journey. From there you can create a SMS activity and everything will be automated.
Using Marketing Cloud APIs: you can create an Apex trigger in your Sales Cloud to call out to Marketing Cloud APIs for SMS send. References: Authenticate v2 token, SMS: Post Message to Number. You need first to create a SMS message in Mobile Connect though.

Only one note that you should use Contact Id/Person Contact Id (003) as Subscriber Key.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/references/mc_rest_transactional_messaging_sms/sendSMSMessageSingleRecipient.html
